# Ember Octane: how to do background upload with web worker?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, concurrency, web-worker

I want to do background uploading with web worker in my ember octane app as we upload very large assets so i have a method inside class as following

```
export default class UtilsUploadComponent extends Component {

private asyncUpload() {
  var worker_fn = () =>
  {
     let data = yield this.sendData(file) // i want to achieve that 
     self.postMessage(data);
   };

   var blob = new Blob(["onmessage ="+worker_fn.toString()], { type: "text/javascript" });

   var worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
   worker.onmessage = function(e)
   {
     console.log(e.data);
   };
   worker.postMessage("start");
   return -1
}

async sendData(file: File, url) { 
   let formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('data', file, file.name);
   const response = await this.apiRequest.POST(url, formData);
   return response.json()
}
}
```

so i want to call send data inside worker function and call post message after i received the data ?

Comment: I still don't understand why people want to upload files in web worker. It does not increase performance of the site.

Comment: so what the other options, we upload very large files over 3GB so we want customer able to upload and in the same time use the app while uploading is going on in the background

Comment: Yeah, so all the javascript that the worker uses has to be sent to the worker as part of the blob. You can't call any javascript outside the blob, because the worker has its own separate environment.

Comment: Maybe this'll help you out? https://twitter.com/dgeb/status/1175147748577939457